# Crystal Report Two page for every record

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Is it possible to create a crystal report with 2 pages for every group record ?
The report requirement is a back to back printing,
the first page data is from sql and the second page is just a static report.

currently this is the design of my report.
[image]

how can I add  a 2nd page for every record so that I can start designing on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities are:

1. Add a second group on the same criteria, so that you have two group headers and footers for every group. Put the content for the static page in the second group footer and make sure you select `New Page Before`
2. Add a second group footer to your existing group. Again, set `New Page Before`. Add a subreport if needed.

Comment: is it on report footer or page footer?

Comment: i follow your option 1.
it works but the only problem is the page header is also repeating on second page of every record

Comment: Suppress the unneeded header so it won't print.

Comment: already got it bro, by adding groupfooter section
Thanks a lot!